# Check for unique item using when-validate-item

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracleforms

I want to check my item to became unique in my database and the item exist in the databasemit must be clear(this item).

So I use trigger when-validate-item for this item and trigger when-timer-expired for the form global.

This is my code :

//trigger when-Validate-item :

```
declare
  i number;    
  vTimer TIMER;
begin
  IF //condition then
      i := show_alert('ERROR');    
      /* Create a timer with a 10 Millisecond delay */
      vTimer :=create_timer('TEMP',10,no_repeat);
  END IF;
end;
```

//trigger when-timer-expired

```
GO_BLOCK ('name_block');    
:name_block.item1:=NULL;
DELETE_TIMER('TEMP');
```

But in runtime, I get this error:

> FRM-40202 Field must be entered

Answer (score 3):

1. to enforce uniqueness, you should use a unique constraint on the table.
2. to clear the item, you can just assign NULL to it in your w-v-i trigger, you don't need a timer; but this is not recommended because it is likely to confuse and irritate your users.
3. you're probably getting FRM-40202 because your timer tries to navigate away from the item which is marked as Required.